# Why is the view model passed to my action method null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't seem to pass the form values using a model.  I do not want to resort to using individual parameter/FormCollection/Request and then instantiate the model class with the values.

My model

```
//JcSpaceAccount.cs
namespace JcSpaceEntities
{
    public class JcSpaceAccount
    {
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public string Email;
        public DateTime DateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

My View

```
//Registration.cshtml
@model JcSpaceEntities.JcSpaceAccount

<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>JcSpaceAccount</h4>
    <hr />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
    }
</div>
```

My controller

```
namespace JcSpace.Areas.Registration.Controllers
{
    public class RegistrationController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Registration/Registration
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(JcSpaceAccount entity)
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not passing the view-model in your `return View()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your model to:

```
public class JcSpaceAccount
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is default MVC `ModelBinder` works with `properties` and you have `fields` in your model now. So default model binder just can't fill them.

Change your `JcSpaceAccount` `fields` to `properties` and you get your data on post.

And in your Post contoller method you should set your model as @haim770 said:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registration(JcSpaceAccount entity)
    {
        ViewData.Model = entity; //This line
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Or by saying `return View(entity)`

Comment: @TryingToImprove yeap

Comment: @teovankot It worked, just remove the semi colon on each field in the model.  The mistake was the model, I didn't really need help on the action method.

Comment: @JcBalantakbo ok, i edit, accept answer if it help you

Answer (score 0):

On your `Registration()` method decorated with `HttpGet`.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        return View(new JcSpaceAccount());
    }
```